# Finding index of maximum element from list

Tags: python, list, indexing, max

Let v be a list of numbers

```
v = [3,5,2,4,8,6,1]
```

Why the following code to find the max element and its index gives an error ? ('int' object is not subscriptable)

```
reduce(lambda x,y: max(x[1],y[1]), enumerate(v))
```

P.S. I know there are other ways to do it, like the one below but I want to understand why the previous one does not work.

```
max(enumerate(v), key= lambda x: x[1])
```

**Epilogue**

Simeon pointed out that my code was really wrong cause lambda should have returned a tuple, not a number. Understanding this, my code could be easily fixed in the following way:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x[1]<y[1] and y or x, enumerate(v))
```

which is, by the way, about 30% slower than

```
max(enumerate(v), key= lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: I accidentally voted to close as a duplicate.  It isn't a duplicate, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're asking why the following does not work:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: max(x[1],y[1]), enumerate(v))
```

Let's see: your input is `enumerate(v)` which iterates over the following elements:

```
[(0, 3), (1, 5), (2, 2), (3, 4), (4, 8), (5, 6), (6, 1)]
```

You intend to reduce these elements with the function `lambda x,y: max(x[1],y[1])`. According to [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reduce), reduce takes a function as input that is applied to two element of the iterable. That means it reduces two elements and returns a value, which is one of the arguments of the next call to reduce.

That means `x` and `y` are tuples. For the above to work, the return value of the lambda function needs to be a tuple again because it's used again in the next reduction. But you are returning an integer, the result of `max`. That's why you're getting an error: "'int' object is not subscriptable" because `x[1]` does not work when `x` is an integer.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for the subtle bug and I couldn't see the big one.

Answer (score 2):

How reduce works:

```
# type annotations:
# reduce(lambda X,X:X, [X,X..]) -> X

#        SAME  <-- result
#          ↗ ↖
#      SAME   SAME]
#        ↗ ↖
#    SAME   SAME,
#      ↗ ↖
# [SAME,  SAME,

>>> reduce(lambda a,b:[a,b], [1,2,3,4])
[[[1, 2], 3], 4]
```

This is how reduce with a seed (a.k.a. fold-left) works:

```
# type annotations:
# reduce(lambda REDU,ELEM:REDU, [ELEM,ELEM..], seed=REDU) -> REDU

#          REDU  <-- result
#            ↗ ↖
#        REDU   ELEM]
#          ↗ ↖
#      REDU   ELEM,
#        ↗ ↖
#    REDU   ELEM,
#      ↗ ↖
#  REDU  [ELEM,

>>> reduce(lambda a,b:[a,b], [1,2,3,4], 'seed')
[[[['seed', 1], 2], 3], 4]
```

You want:

```
maxValue,maxIndex = reduce(
    lambda p1,p2: max(p1,p2), 
    ((x,i) for i,x in enumerate(yourList))
)
```

The important thing to notice about `reduce` is the **types**.
 * When you use reduce(...) with a seed value (known as `fold` in other languages), the *return type will be the seed's type*.
 * When you use `reduce` normally, it ignores the seed element. This works great if all elements of your list are the same type (for example, you can `reduce(operator.mul, [1,2,3])` or `reduce(operator.add, [1,2,3])` just fine, because the reduced output type (int) is the same as the unreduced input type (two ints)). However *the return type will be the same as the list's element's type*.

If your elements are of different types, you need to use reduce(...) in `fold`-mode (i.e. with a seed with the *right semantics*). (The alternative is to special-case your lambda (very ugly).)

*More explicitly, your intended return type is a tuple (the max element and its index, or the reverse). However your reduction function is of type `tuple,tuple -> int`. This cannot work because it violates the contract that reduce demands of your function.*